# fixed position css clear both not working

Tags: html, css

hi im trying to put fixed text at the end of every page like this .. 
[image]
everything working so fine yet but if the page has lots of trs and its full 
the footer will looks like this .. 
[image]
and this is the css for the footer ..

```
.end-footer
{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    clear:both;    
}
```

and this is the html code for the footer

```
<div class='end-footer' style="clear: both;">
    <h3 style="text-align: center;"><strong>Jordan.Amman&nbsp;/ Mob.791075521/Tel.65562555/P.O.Box.950579 &ndash; 11195/Email. cland@theaddress.info</strong></h3>
    <div style="height: 40px; background-color:#23967b"></div>
</div>
```

clear:both not working with fixed position .. 
any help here thanks a lot ..

Comment: Try to fix the height of table with max-height.

Comment: can you write the code please

Comment: try position:sticky instead of fixed :)

Comment: Clear doesn't work with `position:fixed`...its' for clearing *floats*.

Comment: @softya max-height:500px;overflow-y: scroll;

Comment: the end-footer is part of the table so i cant margin it this is the code

Comment: <tr>
 <td colspan='9'>{!! $department['department_bill_terms'] !!}</td>
</tr>